# Making embedded google chart responsive

Tags: javascript, iframe, charts

I have a client that has a lot of embedded google charts linked to published charts from spreadsheets.

Is it possible to make these charts responsive? If the chart was coded by pure javascript without the iframe, that certainly would not be a big issue (I think). But since the drawChart() function in this case is inside the iframe, my guess is that it's hard to do anything about it. It seems like the charts are hard coded in width, with the same settings given as the published chart in the spreadsheet.

Is there anything that can be done to make these charts responsive?

Since I haven't found anything good from my google research, I'm waiting for the doom hammer :)

Comment: remove the `j` tag. it's the tag for a programming language, APL dialect.

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo by me.